# Paginação MVC asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paginação

Atualmente trabalho com os dados assim:

O contexto me retorna todos os Clientes do banco

```
    public IEnumerable<Clientes> ListarTodos()
    {
        return contexto.Clientes.ToList();
    }
```

No controller chamo o ListarTodos()

```
    public PartialViewResult Index()
    {
        var clientes = bdCliente.ListarTodos();
        return PartialView(clientes);
    }
```

E então exibo na View e com JQuery monto a paginação adicionando um campo de busca que faz a pesquisa em cima da tabela já montada. O processo de pesquisa do JQuery é extremamente rápido pois já tem todos os dados na tabela. Porém o tempo para montar a primeira vez a tabela é algo demorado.

Para fazer a paginação, mais eficiente, devo utilizar a paginação no contexto, ou no controller, ou então na View mesmo de outra forma (acredito que não seja a maneira mais eficiente)?  E como ficaria o controller/contexto utilizando a paginação.

Comment: Se pode fazer no Controller !!! é essa a dúvida, ou você quer exemplo de como fazer isso... Na view não é indicado por causa de desempenho

Comment: Mas a lentidão não está no contexto? Não é um processo lento eu trazer do banco todos, e depois filtrar pelo controller? O correto não seria eu trazer já filtrado pelo banco.

Comment: Então @DiegoZanardo, realmente, por isso eu te perguntei se quer um exemplo, porque do jeito que você fez dando um ToList ali ferro a questão de desempenho tem que ser de outra forma para que você só traga o que precisa e monte a paginação. A sua questão não pediu exemplo, só esclarecimento!!!

Comment: Se pudesse me dar um exemplo seria bom. Editei a pergunta!

Comment: você vai ter que adequar ao seu modelo!

Comment: A performance vai depender das suas necessidades. Por exemplo paginar no banco pode ser mais performático porém vai te dar mais trabalho para ordenar/filtrar pois neste caso você teria que fazer uma chamada ao BD sempre que o usuário navegar pelas páginas, reordenar ou filtrar. Paginar no controller é um meio termo e a pior performance "geralmente" é paginar na view mas dai nem de uma chamada ao controller vc precisa quando navegar, ordenar, filtrar

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Baixe pelo Nuget o [**PagedList**](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList) (***PageList e PagedList.Mvc***)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após a instalação faça o seguinte:

Altere esse metodo para `IQueryable` e tire o `ToList()`

***Método***

```
public IQueryable<Clientes> ListarTodos()
{
    return contexto.Clientes;
}
```

***No Controller:***

```
using PagedList;
public PartialViewResult Index(int? page, String filtro)
{
        IQueryable<Clientes> clientes = bdCliente.ListarTodos();
        IPagedList<Clientes> model = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtro) ?
            clientes.Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(filtro)).OrderBy(x => x.Nome).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10) :
            clientes.OrderBy(x => x.Nome).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10);
        return PartialView(model);
}
```

***Obs: Orderby é obrigatório quando se usa ToPagedList.***

***Na View***

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model IPagedList<Clientes>
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPageAdm.cshtml"; }
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Configurações</a>
    </div>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="filtro" value="@ViewBag.Filtro" id="filtro" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Digite a descrição...">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Filtro</button>        
    </form>
</nav>
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%">
            @Html.Raw("Nome Completo")
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
            </td>            
        </tr>
    }
</table>
@if (Model.HasNextPage || Model.HasPreviousPage)
{
    <div style="text-align: center">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, (page) => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page, filtro = @ViewBag.filtro }), PagedListRenderOptions.Classic)
    </div>
}
```

- [**Documentação Completa**](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList)

Comment: Mas esse método é performático?

Comment: Sim, porque ele calcula o que vai ser enviado na tela, e só traz aquilo que precisa, e monta paginação com o calculo de registros. @user3218869. Do jeito que ele ta fazendo ai sim o desempenho é baixo. Assim melhore e muito o trafego de informação.

Comment: +1 Boa! Só uma nota: `@Html.Raw("Nome Completo")` é completamente desnecessário. Você pode escrever o nome da coluna em HTML na mão sem problema algum.

Answer (score 11):

Só pra constar, como alternativa pra quem quiser aprender como fazer isso na mão, de forma simples (não que o `PagedList` não seja, só não revela o que ele faz por baixo dos panos), basta criar um método que aceite a página atual e a quantidade de itens por página e utilizar os métodos `Skip()` e `Take()` do linq:

```
public IEnumerable<Clientes> ListarPagina(int paginaAtual, int itensPorPagina)
{
    return contexto.Clientes.Skip((paginaAtual - 1) * itensPorPagina).Take(itensPorPagina).ToList();
}
```

Se quiser montar os links da paginação e ter um `ViewModel` específico com o que precisa para trabalhar, você pode modificar um pouco o caso e criar um modelo genérico para suas listas paginadas, que aceite o total de registros, a página atual, a quantidade de itens por página e a coleção de itens:

```
public class ListaPaginada<T>
{
    public int TotalItens { get; private set; }
    public int ItensPorPagina { get; private set; }
    public int PaginaAtual { get; private set; }

    public int TotalPaginas
    {
        get { return Math.Ceiling(TotalItens / ItensPorPagina); }
    }

    public List<T> Itens { get; private set; }

    public ListaPaginada(List<T> itens, int totalItens, int itensPorPagina, int paginaAtual)
    {
        this.Itens = itens;
        this.TotalItens = totalItens;
        this.ItensPorPagina = itensPorPagina;
        this.PaginaAtual = paginaAtual;
    }
}



public ListaPaginada<Clientes> ListarPagina(int paginaAtual, int itensPorPagina)
{
    var clientes = contexto.Clientes;
    var totalClientes = clientes.Count();
    var clientesDaPagina = clientes.Skip((paginaAtual - 1) * itensPorPagina).Take(itensPorPagina).ToList();

    return new ListaPaginada<Clientes> (clientesDaPagina, totalClientes, itensPorPagina, paginaAtual);
}
```

Na sua view, você terá um único objeto com as propriedades para fazer os loops e gerar a paginação e a lista como desejar:

```
@model ListaPaginada<Clientes>

if (Model.TotalItens > 0)
{
    foreach(var item in Model.Itens)
    {
        <li>@item.Nome</li>
    }

    if (Model.TotalPaginas > 1)
    {
        <div class="paginacao">
            @for(var i = 1; i < Model.TotalPaginas; i++)
            {
                Url.Action("Index", new { pagina = i })
            }
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    <p>Nenhum item disponível no momento!</p>
}
```

Não recomendo a substituição do componente, apenas apresento uma maneira de fazer o mesmo de forma personalizada, com boa performance e, provavelmente o que o componente faz por baixo dos panos, sem os adicionais desnecessários.

Comment: amigo, poderia me ajudar a fazer esta sua ideia, veja se pode me ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101913/d%C3%BAvida-com-pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-asp-net?noredirect=1#comment208104_101913

Comment: Me desculple. Acredito que houve um erro de digitação no método `Math.Ceil`. Na verdade é `Math.Ceiling`. Corrigi no exemplo.