# Como fazer reload asp.net mvc pagedlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Eu tenho meu grid com o html helper Pagedlist

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Id", "Index", new { OrderBy = ViewBag.OrdenaPorId, FiltroPagina = ViewBag.FiltroPagina })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Nome", "Index", new { OrderBy = ViewBag.OrdenaPorNome, FiltroPagina = ViewBag.FiltroPagina })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Descrição", "Index", new { OrderBy = ViewBag.OrdenaPorDescricao, FiltroPagina = ViewBag.FiltroPagina })
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descricao)
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:right;">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Editar", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deletar(@item.Id)">Deletar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>

<br />
Página @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) de @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, Pagina => Url.Action("Index", new { Pagina, Orderby = ViewBag.AtualOrder, FiltroPagina = ViewBag.FiltroPagina }))
```

Ao clicar em deletar, ele abre uma modal, e a mesma faz um post para a action deletar

Mas aí vem o problema,

Se der erro, deve retornar a mensagem de erro, caso contrário preciso de um "reload" no meu grid

A mensagem de erro, ok, mas e o reload? como faço usando o PagedList?

```
                  $.ajax({
                        url: "Deletar",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { Id: Id},
                        success: function (data) {
                            //Como faço o reload aqui?
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            //Mensagem de erro
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o `Controller` foi implementado [como nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23694/pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mvc-asp-net), o seguinte Ajax deve resolver:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Deletar",
    type: "POST",
    data: { Id: Id},
    success: function (data) {
        window.location.reload(true);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        //Mensagem de erro
    }
});
```

Comment: bem isso Cigano, funcionou, obrigado, aproveitando, conhece algum grid responsivo para indicar? estou sofrendo com minhas escolhas ultimamente, rsrs

Comment: @Rod Qual você está usando? O que exatamente você imagina como responsivo?

Comment: Estou usando o pagedlist mesmo, responsivo apenas que não quebre no layout

Comment: Uso combinado o Bootstrap para as Views, ou então o Zurb Foundation, mas o Foundation exige maior trabalho manual.

Comment: mas e o seu grid de dados? datagrid, qual usa?

Comment: Este: http://www.datatables.net/